# split a line into its components

Tags: perl, split

I need to split the lines of an input file into its columns.

```
ATOM      0  HB3 ALA C 999      28.811  -7.680  12.279  1.00 57.53           H   

ATOM   7637  N   PRO C1000      27.299  -5.667  10.647  1.00216.82           N
```

The code I have works fine, as long as the 6th column is <1000, or shorter than 4 digits:

```
($ATOM, $atom_num, $atom_type, $res, $chain, $res_num) = split(" ", $pdb)
```

However as soon as column 6 reaches 1000, it will no longer discriminate the two columns. I am no expert in perl, but the code I am dealing with is perl, so I need to figure out how to split this e.g. by the number of digits of each column.
Any suggestions?

Comment: split on position. all columns seem to have the same width.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. They do not have all the same width though. E.g. column 5 (where it says 'C') has the length of 1 digit.

Comment: the columns are the same length for each row i mean. Column 5 has length of 1 for each row. So each column always start at the same place. Therefor you can split on position. This is at least true for the example you showed.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by using unpack and defining the length of each column.
$format = 'A6 A6 A5 A4 A1 A5';
($ATOM, $atom_num, $atom_type, $res, $chain, $res_num) = unpack($format, $pdb);

Comment: Nice solution. But there are also [some Perl modules](https://www.google.de/search?q=perl+read+pdb) out there that do parse PDB files, for instance [`Bio::PDB::Structure`](http://search.cpan.org/~rulix/Bio-PDB-Structure-0.02/lib/Bio/PDB/Structure.pm). No idea whether they are good, but they exist.